# Renjin - could not find function 'png'

Tags: java, r, renjin

I am a newbie to Renjin, but experienced in java. My R coding skills are slowly picking up, I am able to run the following script in RStudio

```
data("iris")
dev.new()
png(filename = "test21.png")
plot(iris)
dev.off()
```

and I can get a png output

with Renjin When I try the same code I get error

```
String path = "png(filename='test21.png')";
Engine.eval("dev.new");
Engine.eval(path);
Engine.eval("plot(iris)");
Engine.eval("dev.off");
```

The error is "could not find function 'png'" - it seems renjin does not have this package what could be the solution to this?? so far I have not found anything on google

Comment: `png` is from the grDevices package, which is a base R package. `png` redirects plotting output to a png graphic device. You probably have to manage graphic devices on the java side instead. Can't help you further though.

Answer (score 1):

Renjin indeed doesn't support R graphics yet and probably not in foreseeable future. Indeed handeling graphics on Java side as Roland suggested is currently the only way.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to do the same from `renjin` studio, the error message is more explicit:

[image]

As a workaround, you could try to manage the graphics from Java instead, as suggested by @Roland.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, My goal at the end is to render graphs into a jsp page where all calculations and produced images should be handled by R, so far the java.awt.Graphics seems to be the best package to handle 2D graphics if I have to separate functionality. my question would be "how do I transfer the plotted data to java for it to handle the remaining bit?" any sample code will be helpful.